# how to statically obtain filename and line numbers that lead to a variable setting in C?

Tags: c, static-analysis

I have a large software system written in C. I have all the sources. I am trying to find a tool that can help me determine (preferably via static analysis) the functions and line numbers that can set a variable that is of interest to me. Example:

```
void func_a(int q) {
   int z;
   ...
   z = q*2;
   ....
   func_b(z);   //  I NEED TO FIND OUT ALL LINES in ALL FILES that can set "z"
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
     int x;
     ...
     x = 38;
     ...
     func_a(x);
}
```

I would like to be told:

```
main()   x = 38;
func_a(x);
void func_a(int q);
func_a() z = q*2;
```

Above 4 lines determine value of z that I am about to send to func_b().

I have examined clang, gtags (with --idutils), and some others. I can not determine if this is something that is supported. Naturally main() and func_a() can be in different .c files and have lots of other lines unrelated to my variable of interest (its a large software system.)

Any hints appreciated.

Comment: Given that C has pointers which may point to any object in the program of appropriate type, this is probably impossible in general (halting problem).

Comment: How large is your code base? Millions of lines of C code?

Comment: Are any of the variables you care about global? Do you ever take any of their addresses? If the answer to either is "yes", then this is basically impossible, but if they're both "no", then there's a possibility.

Comment: My code base is large, certainly in 100s of thousands of lines. For sake of inquiry I wish to ignore the C-pointer issue initially. (If I take a pointer to a variable, I would like to then flag any changes thru that pointer as a potential change to my variable of interest.)

No global variables, again for sake of initial inquiry. I realize no perfect or complete solution may be possible, but can a tool at least help determine lines of code where my variable may have been set from, directly or indirectly?

Answer (score 1):

> I have a large software system written in C. I have all the sources. I am trying to find a tool that can help me determine (preferably via static analysis) the functions and line numbers that can set a variable that is of interest to me.

### This problem is unsolvable. See [Rice's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rice%27s_theorem)

The intuition is that if you have some [automatic variable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Automatic_variable) `x`, you could pass its address `&x` elsewhere, and arbitrarily. You'll have complex [pointer aliasing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pointer_aliasing).

However, you could consider using [Frama-C](https://frama-c.com/) (with manually added annotations in [ACSL](https://frama-c.com/acsl.html)) or [Clang static analyzers](https://clang-analyzer.llvm.org/), and debuggers. Notice that [GDB](https://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/) provide [watchpoints](https://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb/Set-Watchpoints.html).

If your C compiler is a recent [GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/), you might code your own [GCC plugin](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gccint/Plugins.html) to help you (and analyze the [GIMPLE](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gccint/GIMPLE.html) representation of your program). Expect a few weeks or months of work. With old versions of GCC, the unmaintained [GCC MELT](http://starynkevitch.net/Basile/gcc-melt/) (which I wrote) might be useful.